# How can I detect the SIM card is not inserted in Android?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I would like to check whether the SIM card is present in the phone every time the phone is booted. If there is no SIM card inserted, the application will delete all the SMS messages, removing all account credentials, deleting all phone contacts, and wiping all data on external storage automatically. But when i boot my phone, the application gets force close... The Toast that I configured is not appeared as well... Can I know how can I check the absence of SIM card? I have tried simSerial.equals("") and simSerial.equals(null), but failed... Need someone help for this... Thanks

```
if (simSerial.equals(null)){
            Toast.makeText(testContext.getApplicationContext(), "No SIM card detected!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("Message", "No SIM card");

            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));   
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                cr.delete(uri, null, null);
            }

            accManager = AccountManager.get(context);
            Account [] acc = accManager.getAccounts();
            if (acc.length > 0){            
                for (int j=0; j<acc.length; j++){
                    Account accountToRemove = acc[j];
                    accManager.removeAccount(accountToRemove, null, null);
                }
            }

            ContentResolver cr1 = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor1 = cr1.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null, null,null);
            try {
                  while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
                     int id = cursor1.getInt(0);
                     cr1.delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                  }
                } finally {
                  cursor.close();
                }

            //Wipe data on SD card
            wipeSdCard();
        }
```

Comment: Just a warning: A pretty common problem for me, on two different models from two different makers, is that the SIM card is not always recognized (due to some glitch in the hardware). You should really inform your users about this very real circumstance that may make your program delete all data erroneously.

Comment: it is actually an anti theft apps... when the phone is stolen, and the theft switch on the phone without putting any SIM card, he can actually access all the data in the phone... so my idea is to delete all data once no SIM card is detected...

Comment: I understand that, just warning you about the possibility of a misfire.

Comment: but i still couldnt detect the SIM card unavailable in the apps